# XAMPP - Port 80 in use by "Unable to open process" with PID 4

Tags: apache, xampp, port80

I faced a problem after installing XAMPP and trying to enable apache services :

`ERROR:`

XAMPP - Port 80 in use by "Unable to open process" with PID 4

`Some Solutions:`

Install Classic Skype to disable the "Use port 80 and 443 for additional incoming connections" checkbox

`Results:`

Unfortunately that solution didn't solve the problem.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: **@NicoHaase**, sorry for the late reply and thanks for your comment, I got the solution by executing the following command `net stop was /y` Or Open the Run dialog box **(press Win+R)**, then type: **services.msc** Then search for **World Wide Web Publishing Service (WWW-Publishing Service)** and **Web Deployment Agent Service** and stop them. You should also disable them.

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution by executing the following command:

`net stop was /y`

Or Open the Run dialog box **(press Win+R)**, then type: **services.msc** Then search for **World Wide Web Publishing Service (WWW-Publishing Service)** and **Web Deployment Agent Service** and stop them. You should also disable them.

Comment: @Reeti When I try to do the last step, i.e., Services and ports, I get a error: – 

The error is "Cannot complete C:\Xampp\xampp-controll.ini. Access denied. I suspect I need to do all these changes in Admin but don't know how to do so. What am I missing? – 
Ed S
 22 secs ago

Answer (score 0):

I know that you already resolved the issue, but stopping a service shouldn't be an answer to open up the port.

You should either change port number in configuration of service which is already using that port, i.e., WWW-publishing service.

Or you should use a different port for apache (xampp). For changing port in apache, open xampp control panel and go to config file of apache(httpd). In it search for "Listen" word it would be set to 80 change it to a port number you want such as 8081. Also in the same file search "ServerName localhost:80" and change it to same port number you set before (i.e. 8081). Save this file without modifying anything else.

Go back to control panel and open xampp control panel config, in there select Services and ports option, in new open tab you will find apache main port set to 80, change it to 8080.

This should solve your problem without removing other services.

Comment: Actually I want to use localhost /path without adding:8081 or other ports, your solution is correct and I already tried it and it works fine